# A problem of first line of yasnippet

Tags: yasnippet

My yasnippet version is 0.8.0 and emacs is 25.0.50
I want to add a default value
And I use following code.

```
# -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
# name: matrix
# key: y_ma
# binding: direct-keybinding
# --


\left ${1:[}
\begin{array}{${3:ccc}}
    $0  \\
\end{array}
\right$2
```

But when I use this code 
it shows directly

```
\left ${1:[}
```

Instead of

```
\left [
```

But if I change `\begin{array}{${3:ccc}}` into `\begin{array}{${3:[}}` for a test. It works

Comment: I think this is either a bug or an undocumented (as far as I can tell) feature in yasnippet different from but related to something like this: https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/issues/640 It looks like it is escaping/matching your closing`}` in the line `\left ${1:[}` whereas in `{${3:[}}` you have extra braces. If you don't get an answer here, you should open an issue on the yasnippet github page.

Comment: Looks more like [#636](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/issues/636) (could be a separate bug though)